# Como enviar mis variables Z al subproceso?

Tags: c++, c, pseint

Estoy tratando de que los valores que pido para las variables Z se utilizen en el sub proceso, esto para que pueda variar la funcion. Es un proceso matematico que estoy realizando, especificamente es el metodo de newton 
...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

SubProceso F <- funcin(x)

```
F = (z5*x^5)-(z4*x^4)+(z3*x^3)-(z2*x^2)+(z1*x)+z0;
```

FinSubProceso

Proceso MSU

```
Definir i Como Entero;
Definir fx, x, n, h, integrala, integralb, intab Como Real;
Definir z5,z4,z3,z2,z1,z0 Como Real;

Escribir "Ecuacion z5x^5 - z4*x^4 + z3*x^3 - z2*x^2 + z1*x + z0";
Escribir "";
Escribir  "Ingresa el valor de Z0: "; Leer z0;
Escribir  "Ingresa el valor de Z1: "; Leer z1;
Escribir  "Ingresa el valor de Z2: "; Leer z2;
Escribir  "Ingresa el valor de Z3: "; Leer z3;
Escribir  "Ingresa el valor de Z4: "; Leer z4;
Escribir  "Ingresa el valor de Z5: "; Leer z5;
Escribir "";
Escribir "Ingresar el valor de a: "; Leer a;
Escribir "Ingresar el valor de b: "; Leer b;
Escribir "Numero de trapecios: "; Leer n;


s1 = 0;
s2 = 0;
x = a;
h = (b-a)/n;

integrala = (400/6)*(a^6) - (900/5)*(a^5) + (675/4)*(a^4) - (200/3)*(a^3) + (25/2)*(a^2)+ 0.2*a;
integralb = (400/6)*(b^6) - (900/5)*(b^5) + (675/4)*(b^4) - (200/3)*(b^3) + (25/2)*(b^2)+ 0.2*b;

intReal = integralb - integrala; //valor de la integral real

Escribir "";

Si n=2 Entonces

    x = x+h;
    s1 = s1 + funcin(x);
    area = (h/3)*(funcin(a)+funcin(b)+(4*s1)+(2*s2));

    Escribir "El area es: ",area;
SiNo
    lim2 = ((n/2)-1);
    Para i<-1 Hasta lim2 Con Paso 1 Hacer

        x = x+h;
        s1 = s1+funcin(x);

        x = x+h;
        s2 = s2+funcin(x);

    Fin Para

    x = x+h;
    s1 = s1+funcin(x);

    area = (h/3)*(funcin(a)+funcin(b)+(4*s1)+(2*s2));

    Escribir "";
    Escribir "El area es : ",area;

Fin Si


error = ((intReal - area)/intReal)*100;

Escribir "";
Escribir "integral real = ",intReal;
Escribir "";
Escribir "El error es: ",error;
```

FinProceso

Comment: Añade el código como texto, no como foto

Answer (score 0):

para tu caso deberías pasar por la firma de tu subproceso las variables z, sería de este modo:

```
SubProceso F <- funcion(_z0, _z1, _z2, _z3, _z4, _z5)
F = (_z5*x^5)-(_z4*x^4)...etc
FinSubProceso
```

tomando en cuenta que donde se llame a tu subproceso envíes las variables definidas:

```
funcion(z0, z1, z2, z3, z4, z5)
```

Comment: No entendi muy bien como es que debo colocarlo, pero veo que no tomaste en cuenta x en funcion(x). trate de ponerlo funcion (x,z0,z1,z2,z3,z4,z5), pero me marca error. Puse el codigo completo y funciona pero quiero poder añadirle mis valores a la funcion.